# Changing the label foreground on mouseover, but the label is inside of button content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, mouseevent

I am new at WPF and XAML, but still as I was reading about this is tricky thing. The thing what I want to change on mouseover is the `Label` foreground color, but the label is inside of the button content. Everything should be done by styles, without `C#`.

```
<Button Name="Home_Button" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Home_Click" Background="Gray" Foreground="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
   <DockPanel>
       <Image Source="Images/icons/home.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-90,0,0,0" />
       <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="0,0,-90,0" Foreground="LightGray" FontSize="12">Home</Label>
   </DockPanel>
</Button>
```

My style settings looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MetroButton">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultFont}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,6" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBorder">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.7" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.3" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ActiveContent">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ActiveContent">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Background"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement"
                               Fill="{DynamicResource ControlsDisabledBrush}"
                               IsHitTestVisible="false"
                               Opacity="0"
                               RadiusY="3"
                               RadiusX="3" />
                    <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder"
                            Background="{DynamicResource GrayBrush8}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Opacity="0" />
                    <Border x:Name="ActiveContent"
                            Background="LightGray"
                            Opacity="0" 
                            />
                    <Border x:Name="PressedBorder"
                            Background="{DynamicResource GrayBrush5}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Opacity="0" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusRectangle"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource TextBoxMouseOverInnerBorderBrush}"
                               RadiusY="4"
                               RadiusX="4"
                               Margin="-1"
                               Opacity="0" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusInnerRectangle"
                               StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource TextBoxMouseOverBorderBrush}"
                               RadiusX="3"
                               RadiusY="3"
                               Opacity="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I wanna change the `Foreground.Color` on `MouseOver` on the `Label` which is inside of the `Button`. Right now the style settings only change the `Background` of the `Button` on `MouseOver`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a sub style for Label inside the Style.Resources of your button style, this is a cut down example but should explain what I'm trying to say.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Gray">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- This represents your image/-->
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Label FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="172,122,131,79" Foreground="Green">
            test
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Label style won't apply to anything outside of the Button, if you mouse over any part of the button area it'll turn the top half blue but will only turn the text green if the mouse is over the bottom half (which is covered by the label)

Comment: Yeah but this will trigger the mouseover on the label, not the button.. I need change the foreground of label when the mousover is triggered on the button, or mb I am wrong? Because I did something similar and didn't worked out.

Comment: Will do both, when the mouse is over any part of the button (including the label) the background colour will change, when the mouse is over the label the background stays changed and now the foreground also changes.

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
<Button Height="36" Margin="286,274,0,0" Width="74" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter_1">
       <Label x:Name="mylbl" Content="Test" MouseEnter="mylbl_MouseEnter"/>
</Button>
```

code behind:

```
private void mylbl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      mylbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Comment: I think I missed the part "Without C#".